# Javascript output functions other than console.log

Tags: javascript, jsbin

Am using JS Bin and am just starting to study Javascript. In the book am using the output is shown using console.log(function). That does not show anything, and am being forced to use alert(function) to see the output. Are there any other ways i can see the output in JS Bin. Also where exactly does console.log output it, cos command prompt does not show anything.

Comment: try with `function write(message) { document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += message + '<br/>'; }` with html `<p id="message"></p>`

Comment: `console.log` is shown in the console of the browsers developer tools. If not there might be a filter set, which logs are shown.

Comment: Press f12 and click the 'console' tab to see console.log("something")'s output

Answer (score 5):

JS bin has a 'Console' Tab, alongside html, css, javascript and output tabs.

Typing console.log in javascript tab displays the output in the console tab.

Comment: But the OP asked *except for* console.

Comment: OP asks where console output is displayed - see "Also where exactly does console.log output it"

Comment: Right you are @deadlysyntax. It was a part of the question. I got distracted by the title and most of his question. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking jsBin.com or jsFiddle.com or bootply.com or some other playground, then

```
document.write('foo=' + foo);
```

works great.  But don't do that in the real world, it is a XSS vulnerability vector.